# Can not read @Value annotation value in Disposable bean

Tags: java, spring

My class looks like

```
public class LevelDBStore implements DisposableBean {
  @Value("${leveldb.maxOpenFiles:1000}")
  private String maxOpenFilesValue;

 public LevelDBStore(String storeName, long cacheSizeInMb, int maxOpenFiles,DBComparator dbComparator) {
     storeLocation = new File(STORE_HOME, storeName);
     db = init(storeLocation, cacheSizeInMb, maxOpenFiles, dbComparator);
     isValid = true;
}

 private DB init(File storeLocation, long cacheSizeInMb, int maxOpenFiles,
  DBComparator dbComparator) {
    logger.info("MaxOpenFilesValue=" + maxOpenFilesValue);
   }
  .....
}
```

When this code runs, I get

```
11 Jan 2016 14:33:14,325 [INFO ] [main] LevelDBStore         | MaxOpenFilesValue=null
```

What is wrong here? I generally works with other beans but not with `DisposableBean`

Comment: how do you call .init?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling .init from your constructor. Spring's injection mechanism is triggered after the actual object construction so injected members are not available from constructors.

Do not call .init directly but put a @PostConstruct annotation on the method. Spring will call it automatically after the construction and the injections are completed.

Answer (score 2):

Fields annotated with `@Value` are processed after the object is created (i.e., after the constructor is finished). You call your init method in the constructor, so the field is not yet initialized.

You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation on your init method, then the method will be executed after the object creation is finished.